# Filling in the missing value does not work properly in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-mining, missing-data

I have a dataset that has a number of numeric variables and a number of ordinal nominal variables. To fill in the missing value I want to use the mode for nominal variables. The following code does not fill some of the nominal value. Please advise why the code is wrong.

```
df = pd.read_csv(sample.csv')
nominal_data = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.object])
nominalColumns= list(set(nominal_data.columns))
df[nominalColumns]=df[nominalColumns].fillna(df[nominalColumns].mode())


age | class
------------
 1 |  no
 2 |  yes
 3 |  NAN
 4 |  yes
 5 |  no
 6 |  NAN
 7 |  no
 8 |  yes
 9 |  no
10 |  NAN
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your column can only store two values, why don't use extract the value to use from the mode ? Providing a `Series` object (which is the return of `.mode()`) may not work as (from my experience), `Series` objects are expected to provide the replacement value for each index (which is not the case with `.mode()` function).

Also, since you want to replace values over a column, use `axis=1`.

Maybe you could try :

```py
df[nominalColumns]=df[nominalColumns].fillna(df[nominalColumns].mode().iloc[0], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.mode` returns a `DataFrame` (see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html)) because each column may have several modes. When you call `df.fillna(x)` where `df` and `x` are both DataFrames with length `n` and `m`, only the first `m` rows of `df` will be filled with the corresponding values in `x`. Thus you need to call `.iloc[0]` after `.mode()` to get the first row as a Series. See example below.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": ["foo", "bar", "foo", None, "foobar"],
    "b": ["foo", "bar", "bar", "foobar", None],
    "c": [None, None, None, "foo", "bar"],
    "d": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})

nominal_data = df.select_dtypes(include=[object])
nominal_columns= list(set(nominal_data.columns))

print(df[nominal_columns].mode())

     b    c    a
0  bar  bar  foo
1  NaN  foo  NaN
```

Column `c` has two modes (`foo` and `bar`), hence the two rows. Columns `a` and `b` only have one mode, hence the `NaN` on the second row.

Using only the first row of modes fills NAs as you expect:

```py
print(df[nominal_columns].fillna(df[nominal_columns].mode().iloc[0]))

        b    c       a
0     foo  bar     foo
1     bar  bar     bar
2     bar  bar     foo
3  foobar  foo     foo
4     bar  bar  foobar
```